# TLS Performance in Java?

Tags: java, performance, ssl

I see the TLS implementation in Java doesn't use JNI at all. A native implementation for TLS should be faster IMO. So I guess maybe JNI itself is too expensive, compared to the benefits of native TLS.

So, how about the TLS performance in Java, or should I have to avoid it whenever possible?

Comment: You should measure the actual performance - or find results from people who did - before making assumptions about Java being slower than another (native) implementation.

Comment: Some functionality is written in native code when it proves to be faster. e.g. zlib compression.  If there were a big difference, I would imagine it would have been migrated already.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that native Java code is slow? It is compiled to machine code, just as your native implementation would be.

For now, just use the native TLS, and if it *proves* to be a bottleneck, you can still optimize it. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

I did a study on this a couple of years ago. 1700 data points. TLS over the Internet is 1/3 the speed of plaintext. Surprising? The bottleneck is the network, not TLS.

Comment: Specifically, the bottleneck is latency.  The speed of light is too slow.  http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/44/TCP%20and%20the%20Lower%20Bound%20of%20Web%20Performance%20Presentation.pdf